# dsx writing to blue-mix object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, data-science-experience

Will bluemix object storage ever have folder capability inside a container like amazon s3. I am not sure about other folks but pretty soon writing from DSX, it gets such a mess in a container. Its like a computer with no capability of creating folders under C:\ drive . Its a complete mess.

Since its DSX's primary storage, is the DSX pushing for this capability.[Bluemix object storage no folder capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj4fH.jpg)

Here's the  s3 container and how beautifully you can organize everything [S3 conatiner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qi6H.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

i believe what you are looking for is something like subcontainers and to organize your files.

I think Object-storage service is based Openstack Object Storage and according to Openstack doc it is not possible to create nested directories.

https://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-swift-pseudo-hierarchical-folders-directories.html

You can use the path in the filename to simulate subdirectories by seperating with / when writing/reading file you can use something like this 'swift://containername.' + name + '/foldername/fillename.csv'
So anything you write with /foldername/filename.csv will be organized under foldername.

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Yes did that, and see the mess it creates. Every thing is under the same root. Not sure how one can handle all that in a single container if you have 50 plus notebook writing parquet etc. As my image shows this is a huge limitation for dsx and this capability should be added to open-stack if missing. Currently I am moving all my writes to s3 as the folder structure is easy to manage.

Comment: Agreed about the limitation and the issue , One of the thing you can workaround at moment and limit the number of files it creates by repartitioning your dataframe or rdd to 1 using df.repartition(1) before writing it to Object storage so that instead of it writing many patitioned files. It will create least of 2-3 files, if you even go deeper, you can write in compress codec. Note:- You can't read them in parallel since you write everything in one partition.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the suggestions. This question apart, I really want to thank you for all the replies that you make asap and willingness to help. THANKS A LOT!